# Material Design Buttons and other components

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Im trying to make an application Lollipop & Material Design compatible following the latest guidelines.

Anyhow I'm having troubles finding the appropriate documentation for the components for Lollipop on developer.android.com it kinda seems like the documentation is stuck with KitKat and appropriate documentation is missing.

I have the need to implement Flat Buttons like these (http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons)  and Icon Toggles like these (http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-other-buttons).

Besides that I'm also trying to implement big style App Bar/Toolbar - again can't find an appropriate documentation.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the new tool bar api have a look at `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html`

`http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html`

for button styles you just need to use elevation
`https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html`

for buttons togglers just use selectors / ripple effect 
`https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html`

gl

Comment: This was useful, I also found this tutorial was also quite useful: http://trickyandroid.com/simple-ripple-reveal-elevation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you are looking for and want to achieve for the material design look and feel.
The url's you have are more the design guidelines. About how everything should look. It's as important as the developers guidelines if you design too.

**Material Activity transitions**

But when you think about the material design transitions where they don't want those static transitions like "Go from this activity to another" But more like a dynamic transition you can look for examples and explanation here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

**Ripples**

If you want to know more about the touchy ripple effects and things like how to get the 'hairline' color of components you can find more here: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

**Elevation**

Also Material design wants you to play more with the elevation of elements. Check that here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

And ofcourse there is more. Look in the left menu where you can find more best practice examples. Also the new Android 21.+ SDK offers new examples released a couple of weeks ago. Check those out to see how google implements Material design for api level 21.+

Comment: No Daniel I know what Material Design is all about, the think is I was missing some more specific guidelines or tutorials regarding the things I listed out.